# IntentService not starting automatically after phone reboot unless app is started

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I'm trying to send a notification at a particular time, this part works perfectly but after I reboot the phone, the service doesn't get started unless the app is opened which then starts the service. I've tried multiple solutions online but still can't fix the issue.

**Activity:**

```
private void startNotificationAlarm() {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderBroadcastReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), intent, 0);
    Objects.requireNonNull(alarmManager).setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**`BroadcastReceiver`:**

```
public class ReminderBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
        intent.setAction("<package>.Receiver");
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

    } else {

        scheduleNotification(context, intent);
    }
}

private void scheduleNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, BaseApp.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_calendar_alert)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(color)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), notification);
}
```

**`IntentService`:**

```
public class BootService extends IntentService {

public BootService() {
    super("BootService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            startNotification();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**`Manifest`**

```
<receiver
        android:name=".Receiver.ReminderBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".Service.BootService"/>
```

Comment: Could you post your manifest file?

Comment: I'll post it when I get home but all the necessary code is in the manifest. I don't think the issue is from the manifest.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide below permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Also you have to make `android:exported` as `true`
as per android docs:

> android:exported
>
> Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and
>   "false" if not. If "false", the only messages the broadcast receiver
>   can receive are those sent by components of the same application or
>   applications with the same user ID.

**sample code**

```
<receiver android:name=".sample.BootReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I have that permission provided in my manifest. I only forgot to include it in the question.

Comment: For me ,on phone reboot I gets the broadcast and able to see the toast msg on screen  that I had added in broadcast receiver.

Comment: I'll try other phones and see if the issue still persists

Comment: I changed to `android:exported=true` but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: did you try to show toast from onReceive() method ? just to confirm if above setup works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198502/discussion-between-tony-and-ashok-kumar).